Why do we add a symmetric rank one matrix in the quasi-newton method SR-1 update?
I'm following Practical Methods of Optimization by Fltecher R..
The quasi-newton condition is given by
$$\mathbf{H}^{(k+1)} \gamma^k = \delta^k$$
Where $\gamma^k=\nabla f(x^{(k+1)}) - \nabla f(x^{(k)})$ and $\delta^k = x^{(k+1)}- x^{(k)}$.
He goes on to say that there are many ways to achieve this condition and a simple way to achieve this is to add a symmetric rank one matrix to $\mathbf{H}^{(k)}$ i.e.,
$$\mathbf{H}^{(k+1)} = \mathbf{H}^{(k)}+a\mathbf{uu^T}$$
Then he multiplis both sides by $\gamma^k$ and equates it to $\delta^k$ in the previous equation as follows,
$$\mathbf{H}^{(k)}\gamma^k+a\mathbf{uu^T}\gamma^k=\delta^k$$
He concludes that, $\mathbf{u}$ is proportional to $\delta^k-\mathbf{H}^{(k)}\gamma^k$.
My question is what is the reason we add $a\mathbf{uu^T}$ to $\mathbf{H}^{(k)}$. It seems random to me. Because, although adding $a\mathbf{uu^T}$ ensures symmetry of $\mathbf{H}^{(k+1)}$ it doesn't ensure positive definiteness.

If $a > 0$, then $a \mathbf{uu}^T$ is necessarily positive semidefinite. Adding a positive definite and positive semidefinite matrix is guaranteed to produce a positive definite matrix

@BenGrossmann Yes! The way Fletcher chose $a$ will make sure that $\mathbf{H}^k$ is positive semidefinite. Thank you.

SR1 can be advantageous when used for approximating Hessian  of non-convex objective function (or more generally of Lagrangian for nonlinearly-constrained problem) because it does not necessarily maintain positive definiteness, and can match the (in)definiteness of the Hessian it is approximating. Therefore, it can work better than BFGS on some non-convex problems.
